# C# reference type questions

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference

```
 public class TreeNode
{
    public TreeNode Left;
    public TreeNode Right;
    public int Data { get; set; }

    public TreeNode(int data)
    {
        Left = null;
        Right = null;
        Data = data;
    }
}



   public class BinarySearchTree
{
    private TreeNode _root;

    public BinarySearchTree()
    {
        _root = null;
    }

    public void Insert(int data)
    {
        TreeNode tempNode = null;

        Insert(_root, tempNode);
    } 

    private void Insert(TreeNode treeNode, TreeNode newNode)
    {
        newNode = new TreeNode(3);
        treeNode = new TreeNode(4);
   }
```

In this example, public void `Insert(int data)` method basically just calls private method, and I put a break point at end of the `public void Insert(int data)` method.

and notice `_root` is still null, and `tempNode` is 4. I don't understand why? Can anyone explain please?

Comment: Does the code compile? Where is newNode defined in Insert(int)?

Comment: You are passing the reference by value. If you did treeNode.DoWork() it would act on the referenced object, but if you reassign treeNode, you are reassigning the reference itself (which was passed by value).

Comment: Framework Design Guidelines (a book by Krzysztof Cwalina and Brad Abrams) recommend to avoid both ref and out parameters. There is rarely a good reason to use `out` and `ref`.

Comment: My question is why _root is still null, and tempNode is 4.

Comment: @retide: Use the `ref` keyword, at both the function and the call.

Comment: Please consider naming methods in a way that make expected behavior related to the name. Right now "Insert" is more like "CreateSomeNodes"...

Answer (score 3):

To pass classes by reference use `ref` keyword:

```
private void Insert(ref TreeNode treeNode, ref TreeNode newNode)
{
    newNode = new TreeNode(3);
    treeNode = new TreeNode(4);
}
```

In your original method only **copies** of references to classes are passed, they are not passed by reference. So if you are doing `new` you are just replacing local copies of class references, but calling method still keeps the original reference values. As a result, newly created values are not returned back to the caller.

Change your `Insert(data)` method (without `ref` keyword compiler will give you an error):

```
public void Insert(int data)
{
    TreeNode tempNode = null;
    Insert(ref _root, ref tempNode);
}
```

This is actually a compiler requirement, just to make sure that the caller is aware that object passed may be replaced by other object after the method call.

You may also want to read about `out` keyword. While `ref` parameters should be initialized before the call, `out` parameters are expected to be initialized inside of the method.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a reference type, but it actually passes a copy of the reference. Updating that copy does not update the original.

To resolve this, either have method return the new value. Or you can rework your function to use out parameters.

```
private void Insert(out TreeNode treeNode, out TreeNode newNode)
{
    newNode = new TreeNode(3);
    treeNode = new TreeNode(4);
}
```

Comment: There should be nothing wrong with using `ref` here since he is creating a new object as long as he uses the `ref` keyword in both the function and function call.

Comment: +1 to all ref/out suggestions. Unfortunately original name of the method makes very hard to understand what is expected behavior is...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `out`, and `ref` modifiers for parameters.  For example, you could

```
private void Insert(ref TreeNode treeNode, TreeNode newNode)
```